# How do I save to a sqlite database using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sqlite

I am developing a webpage for offline CRUD for a sqlite database using sqlite.
I have little experience with javascript, none with jquery, and a little with sqlite but none with developing it within javascript.  I began using this tutorial
[here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1940-My-Safari-Browser-SQLite-Database-Hello-World-Example.htm)

I noticed however that the data doesn't seem to be writing to the database itself and is browser dependent.  If I open it with Chrome it only remembers the data from previous sessions in chrome and if I open it with opera it only reads the data from other sessions in opera.  When I inspect the database file I don't see data being saved to it.

Are there separate databases running in the background of the actual browsers themselves or is this tutorial not saving the data to the database itself?  If it is not saving to the database then how do I save using javascript?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HTML5` has sqlite database.

So.. each browser implements this using `w3c standard`.. This has nothing to do with any local database server. Sqlite is an embeded database...

So.. yes, it is browser dependent...

An example for you: you can compare `sqlite` to `cookies` but cooler :)

Comment: Where is the data being stored?  Do you know of a way to save it to a sqlite database file?

Comment: HTML 5 does **not** have SQLite, and it is **not** a standard, it is a [sperate draft specification that is not undergoing any further development](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/)

Answer (score 0):

The data is stored in a file but you'll need to use procmon or a file system watcher to find out where. For FF it's near where cookies and cache files are saved if I remember correctly.